# Gradle build not finding JAVA_HOME even when its actually there

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am trying to build this project to develop custom `x-pack` plugins (https://github.com/elastic/shield-custom-realm-example)

However, when I try to run `./gradlew` inside the project root I get a `JAVA_HOME must be set to build Elasticsearch` error.

Here are the details on why I don't understand why this error is being thrown.

```
➜  shield-custom-realm-example git:(master) echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
➜  shield-custom-realm-example git:(master) java -version
'java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
➜  shield-custom-realm-example git:(master) ./gradlew

> Configure project :
Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '~/dev/temp/shield-custom-realm-example/build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'x-pack-custom-realm-extension-example'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'elasticsearch.build']
   > JAVA_HOME must be set to build Elasticsearch

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Additionally, I also have these added to my `~/.zshrc` file.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home"
export RUNTIME_JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `./gradlew --stop`, confirm with `env | grep JAVA` that your env vars are exported and try your build again. It happened to me in the past that the Gradle Daemon was started without the env var and did not restart to pick it up.